# What does this type definition actually means?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have started learning TS a few days back and when I was looking on Internet for an express server done with TS I found this as the type definition of the middlewares argument and I don't actually understand it. I have tried to search it in the Typescript docs, but I haven't found anything similar to this.

```
<!-- language: lang-ts -->

    function initializeMiddlewares (middlewares: {
            forEach: (arg0: (middleware: any) => void) => void
        }): void {
            middlewares.forEach(middlewares => {
                this.app.use(middlewares);
            })
    }
```

And if I remove it and just set 'any' as the type I get the following code and this error

```
TS7006: Parameter 'middlewares' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

```
<!-- language: lang-ts -->

    function initializeMiddlewares(middlewares: any): void {
        middlewares.forEach(middlewares => {
            console.log(middlewares)
            this.app.use(middlewares);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type definition says that `initializeMiddlewares` is a function that tags an argument (`middlewares`) which returns `void`, and `middlewares` is something that has a `forEach` method; the `forEach` method is a function that tags an argument (`arg0`), which is another function which takes an `any` (`middleware`); that inner function returns void, and the outer function also returns void.

Your error when you changed things might look confusing because the name `middlewares` is shadowed; it's referring to the inner name in the `forEach`. If you want to use implicit any, you would need to change your `tsconfig.json`: `"noImplicitAny": false`.

Breaking it down bit by bit can help understand complex types:

```
function initializeMiddlewares (
  // middlewares argument
  middlewares: {
    // forEach method which should exist on the middlewares argument
    forEach: 
      // inner function
      arg0: (middleware: any) => void)
    // forEach return
    => void,
  }
// initializeMiddlewares return
): void
{
  middlewares.forEach(middlewares => {
    this.app.use(middlewares);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. With your explanation it has been way easier to understand